# Two complex ListBox inside one ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

Good day, I'm have probably a classic problem. I need put same ListBox inside a ScrollViewer. Yes i know it not good idea.

Actually, in ScrollViewer was put Grid, in what have Expander

And my problem How do mouse scroll of it construction? 
I Can't scroll if anyone listbox item selected.

Now day i know how do organisation mouse scroll one of my style listbox.
But how create mouse scroll of this construction, i don't know

```
<ScrollViewer 
      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <Expander IsExpanded="True" 
                   >
                   <ListBox ***><ListBox/>
                  </Expander>

               <Expander IsExpanded="True" 
                         Grid.Row="2" >
                   <ListBox ***><ListBox/>
                  </Expander>

               <ListBox  ***><ListBox/>
               </Expander>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[An example image of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gmvN.png)

I apologize for the fact that the screen is not translated, and for the "broken language" of the question.

**Edit**

If simplify the task.

The problem will look like:
it is necessary to provide scrolling (the current list or the entire space does not matter) when selecting any items from the list.
If I remove the global scroll, then the problem with determining the height of the listboxes

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0" Width="493" CanContentScroll="True">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" Name="firsrow"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100" Name="secondrow"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="1"  >
                <Expander IsExpanded="True" >
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation= "Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text = "header1" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Grid >
                        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                            <ListBoxItem >
                                <TextBlock Text="1">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem >
                                <TextBlock Text="2">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem  >
                                <TextBlock Text="3">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem >
                                <TextBlock Text="4">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ListBoxItem>                                
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="2"  >
                <Expander   IsExpanded="True">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation= "Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text = "header2" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Grid >
                        <ListBox x:Name="listBox_2"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                            <ListBoxItem >
                                <TextBlock Text="1">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem >
                                <TextBlock Text="2">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem >
                                <TextBlock Text="3">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ListBoxItem>
                            <ListBoxItem >
                                <TextBlock Text="4">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </ListBoxItem>

                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Very unclear what you asking.

Comment: I Can't scroll if anyone listbox item selected

Comment: 1. Very unclear, try to get someone to translate in some understandable English. 2. From what I understand, maybe [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38413d0a-7388-4191-a7a6-fd66e469d502/two-listbox-scrollbar-in-synchronisation?forum=wpf) can help you.

Comment: Thank you Kilazur
link helped only i am processing listBox_PreviewMouseWheel